# Comparador numérico

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

```
print ("Insira dois valores para serem comparados:")



Valor1= float(input("Escreva um número:"))
Valor2= float(input("Escreva outro número:"))


print ("Os números que você inseriu foram esses?","\n", Valor1, "\n", Valor2)

sim = str
não = str

if (str(input())=="não") or (str(input())=="sim"):

if str(input(sim)):
    if (Valor1 > Valor2):
        print ("O primeiro valor é maior que o segundo")

    if (Valor2 > Valor1):
        print ("O segundo valor é maior que o primeiro")

    if (Valor2 == Valor1):
        print ("Os números são iguais")


if str(input(não)):
    print ("Então insira os números corretos")
```

Por que ele fica mostrando a classe da variável `Sim` depois de eu responder se digitei corretamente os valores?

E aparentemente ele pede a resposta mais de uma vez, não entendi o porquê.

Tentei fazer o código utilizando `while` em vez de `if` para começar a condicional e fechar as sequências com `break`, mas o mesmo problema aconteceu.

Comment: Por isso que eu perguntei, você não aceitou a resposta, você só votou, eu percebi que não entendeu a diferença, dá uma olhada de novo no [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código tem uma enorme quantidade de erros. Alguns casos não são bem erros mas deixa o código não tão legível ou não é comum escrever assim:

- Não faço ideia o que sejam essas variáveis `sim` e`não`, só as eliminei já que elas não tem utilidade
- Não converti o `input()` para `str()` porque ele já é uma *string*
- Apenas comparei essa entrada com `sim` e mais nada porque é só assim que deve fazer as comparações, se digitar qualquer outra coisa considerará como errado
- Um laço poderia ser usado aí mas depende de requisito, nada indica na pergunta que tenha, isso pode ter tentando usar por chute
- Preferi usar nomes de variáveis em minúsculo que é o normal, e para manter consistente com as outras
- Preferi não tratar a exceção lançada se não for digitado um número adequado, mas o mais correto é fazer isto
- Tem `if` demais aí e alguns desses `if` funcionarão melhor se forem `elif`s
- Talvez o maior problema é pedir a confirmação várias vezes, isso não faz o menor sentido, é por você ter colocado no código pedindo para digitar várias vezes que está pedindo várias vezes, se quer só uma vez coloque só uma vez.
- Eu recomendaria entender o que cada coisa no código faz antes de usar, colocar coisas aleatórios nele que parecem se encaixar porque viu em algum lugar alguém fazendo algo parecido não vai te fazer aprender programar. Você precisa mudar a forma de aprendizado para progredir.

Veja:

```
print("Insira dois valores para serem comparados:")
valor1 = float(input("\nEscreva um número:"))
valor2 = float(input("\nEscreva outro número:"))
print("\nConfirme os números que você inseriu digitando 'sim':\n", valor1, "\n", valor2)
if input() == "sim":
    if valor1 > valor2:
        print("O primeiro valor é maior que o segundo")
    elif valor2 > valor1:
        print("O segundo valor é maior que o primeiro")
    elif valor2 == valor1:
        print("Os números são iguais")
else:
    print("Então insira os números corretos")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Kf2Q3B). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ComparingInputpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ComparingInput.py).

Comment: Estou tentando afinar esse sentido, sou muito novato na programação e estou tirando bastante leite de pedra para aprender, estou achando muitas coisas confusas, principalmente na hora de escolher os problemas para resolver. 

Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelas dicas com o código :)

Comment: O motivo disso eu identifiquei que é porque está tentando aprender de forma não estruturada, isso não dá certo. Preciso construir o conhecimento um passo de cada vez.

Comment: Sim, mas justamente a minha dúvida é não achar uma forma muito linear de como progredir dentro da programação, parece que tem tanta coisa a ser apreendida que pelo excesso de opções, torna tudo um pouco mais confuso.  
Ainda mais que meu objetivo com a programação em si, é tornar algumas técnicas que uso em física, química e matemática algo mais palatável, porém transcrever isso para uma lógica que o computador entenda, está sendo meu desafio.